# How can I join two tables but only return rows that match

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables, a property table and a buyer table, I'm trying to write a select script that will show a list of properties that have the same number of rooms as the desired number of rooms of a specified customer.

I think I need to use a inner join to pull the data I need but as I'm still new to this I'm getting a little confused. The select script I have written is as follows,

```
SELECT DISTINCT Buyer.Buyer_Surname, Buyer.Rooms_Needed, Property.Property_Address as Property_for_sale, Property.Num_Rooms as Property_No_of_Rooms
FROM Buyer
INNER JOIN Property 
ON Property.Buyer_ID = Buyer.Buyer_ID
WHERE Buyer.Rooms_Needed = '5'
AND Property.Num_Rooms = '5'
AND Buyer.Buyer_ID = '70000';
```

however it is telling me no rows are selected but I know there is a buyer requiring 5 bedrooms and 3 properties in the database with 5 bedrooms.

Here are my tables;

```
CREATE TABLE Buyer 
(
Buyer_ID varchar(5) NULL,                           
Viewing_Data varchar2(50),                          
Maximum_Budget varchar2(50),                        
Purchase_Price varchar2(50),                        
Purchase_Date DATE,                                 
Buyer_Forename varchar2(50),                        
Buyer_Surname varchar2(50),                         
Buyer_Address varchar2(50),                         
Buyer_Town varchar2(50),                            
Buyer_Postcode varchar2(10),
Rooms_Needed varchar2(10),
Seller_ID Varchar2(5),
Staff_ID varchar2(5),
PRIMARY KEY (Buyer_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Staff_ID) REFERENCES Staff(Staff_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Seller_ID) REFERENCES Seller(Seller_ID)
); 

CREATE TABLE Property 
(
Property_ID varchar(5),                              
Property_Address varchar(25),
Property_Town varchar(25),
Property_Postcode varchar(25),                       
Asking_Price varchar2(20),                           
Date_Registered DATE,                                
Property_Type varchar2(50),                          
Num_Rooms varchar2(50),                              
Buyer_ID varchar(5),                                 
Seller_ID varchar(5),                                
Branch_ID varchar(5),                                
PRIMARY KEY (Property_ID),                           
FOREIGN KEY (Buyer_ID) REFERENCES Buyer(Buyer_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Seller_ID) REFERENCES Seller(Seller_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Branch_ID) REFERENCES Branch(Branch_ID)
);
```

Comment: If the bedrooms match, then the buyer ids don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting on Buyer and Property Ids.  You'll be lucky if these line up, but your results still won't be correct.  To join the tables where the house has as many rooms as the buyer would like,  you need to join on the number of rooms:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Buyer.Buyer_Surname, Buyer.Rooms_Needed, 
    Property.Property_Address as Property_for_sale, Property.Num_Rooms as   
    Property_No_of_Rooms
    FROM Buyer
    INNER JOIN Property 
    ON Buyer.Rooms_Needed = Property.Num_Rooms;
```

If you need to filter by number of rooms, you can also append a WHERE at the end:

```
... WHERE Buyer.Rooms_Needed = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this rather then joining on Buyer.Id and Property.BuyerId

```
SELECT DISTINCT Buyer.Buyer_Surname, Buyer.Rooms_Needed, Property.Property_Address as Property_for_sale, Property.Num_Rooms as Property_No_of_Rooms
FROM Buyer
INNER JOIN Property 
ON Property.Rooms_Needed = Property.Num_Rooms 
WHERE Buyer.Buyer_ID = '70000';
```

This will find all properties with the number of required bedrooms by user id 70000.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now.